# Magento 2 Installation Fatal Error - Cannot instantiate interface

Tags: installation, magento-2.1

I have installed a fresh Magento 2.1 over the command line and always get the same fatal error when trying to access the frontend or backend.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\App\Config\Scope\ReaderPoolInterface

Anyone experienced the same? I have found some resources but with no real help.

**Update** 
I have deleted var/di and var/generation and set it to developer mode

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\App\Config\Scope\ReaderPoolInterface in /shop/build/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:73 Stack trace: #0 
/shop/build/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...') #1 
/shop/build/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(126): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...') #2 
/shop/build/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'readerPool', 'Magento\\Framewo...') #3 
/shop/build/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Develo in /shop/build/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 73
```

Comment: Did you try to remove var/generation var/cache and switch to developer mode?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism done both no luck

Comment: Did you install any third party modules before running Magento install ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you use nginx configuration from the official sample and running Magento in the default/developer mode this situation might happen with document root global value set as

```
root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;
```

The issue can be fixed by setting Magento root from pub directory to the root index.php

```
root $MAGE_ROOT;
```

In case of Apache the `DocumentRoot` value change might also fix the situation. 
Hope it will help.

Comment: Setting the web root outside of pub is, overall, not a very good idea.

Answer (score 21):

Make sure the PHP module **intl** is installed, clear `var/generation` (or `generation/*` if you're using Magento 2.2+) and `var/cache`, enable Magento modules (`bin/magento module:enable --all`), compile DI (`bin/magento setup:di:compile`), and then try again.

Comment: Spot on. Disabling any modules before running `setup:install` or `setup:upgrade` is the problem

Comment: Works for me, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

After you downloaded all the files/created the project through composer, you must setup the store. You can do this from the command line:

```
php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --help
```

Or going to: http://mystore.com/setup

Answer (score 2):

I also have this kind of problem when trying to run Magento cli like `magento list` in the terminal. After several hours I tried the solutions but all the answers not work for me. it turns out that the `di.xml` file is lost.

Steps :

- Copy all the missing file from here :

https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.1/app/etc.

- After that run the remove the cache : `rm -rf var/*`.
- Now if you run `magento list` this will work again.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue caused by changing the code without cleaning the cache first. I manually cleaned the cache it solved the issue.

```
sudo rm -rf var/cache
sudo rm -rf var/di
sudo rm -rf var/generation
```