# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\App\ExceptionHandlerInterface in C in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\Mage\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Mage\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Mage\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(100): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Mage\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(121): Magento\Framework\App\Http->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Manager), Object(Magento\Framework\App\AreaList), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Fra in C:\xampp\htdocs\Mage\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php on line 121
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? Like Magento version, other configuration, etc! Do you use Nginx?

Comment: Magento version 2.3.2 And i am use a xampp(Local) Server ANd Xampp server Version is  PHP 7.3.6 (cli) (built: May 29 2019 12:11:00) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125415/magento-2-installation-fatal-error-cannot-instantiate-interface

Comment: @mohit Patel, I Also apply sir But Didn't Work

Comment: above answer link check Erfan man answer