# Magento 2.3.0 to 2.4.3 upgrade issue

Tags: magento2, upgrade, putty

I'm trying to update my Magento 2.3.0 version to 2.4.3 through putty. I'm jumping this much as I need to use composer 2, compatible with 2.4.3, as I have memory limitation. I start by doing first

```
php74 composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3 --no-update

then

php74 composer update

and then 

php74 bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

after this last command line, I get this error here:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface in /home/customer/www/mywebsitename.net/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50
Stack trace:
#0 /home/customer/www/mywebsitename.net/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#1 /home/customer/www/mywebsitename.net/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#2 /home/customer/www/mywebsitename.net/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'cache', 'Magento\\Framewo...')
#3 /home/customer/www/mywebsitename.net/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework in /home/customer/www/mywebsitename.net/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 50
```

I have also tried to download the "vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/" folder from magento and replace the files, but still nothing. Any idea?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125415/magento-2-installation-fatal-error-cannot-instantiate-interface

Comment: Use Composer 1 to upgrade, then move to Composer 2.